# IF any 3 cells contain value = true

Tags: excel

So my questions is how would I do a formula to show true if cell contains "Win" or "Win.1" or "win.3" ,etc

**Example**

```
Name  Game1 Game2 Game3
John  blank blank win.1   = True
Greg  win.5 blank blank   = True
Cris  blank blank blank   = False
Matt  blank WIN.s blank   = True
```

Comment: Are those cells actually blank? Or are they just not "win", "win.1", or "win.3"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `E2`, `=IF(COUNTIF(B2:D2,"win*"),"True","False")` and drag down.

Answer (score 2):

In E2:

If truly blank and no formula then:

```
=COUNTA(B2:D2)>0
```

If they are formulas:

```
=COUNTIF(B2:D2,"<>")>0
```

Then copy/drag down